# iOS PhoneGap camera can't save image to Photo Library

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, photo

I'm sort of stuck with phonegap-iOS problem and I hope someone can help me.

I created a simple app using PhoneGap 1.0. I'd like to take a picture and the save it to photo library. I've read the PhoneGap API documentation. Here is my code.

```
function getImage() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess,
        onFail,
        { 
            quality: 20, 
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        });
}

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    alert("Image taken");
}

function onFail(error) {
    alert("Fail when getting image. Code = " = error.code);
}
```

With that code, I'm able to take a photo using device camera but the photo won't save in picture library. I'm using XCode 4.0.1, device I use to test this code is iPad2 (iOS 4.3.5) and iPhone 3GS (iOS 4.2.1).

Can anyone help me here, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.
Instead of using `getPicture()`, I used `captureImage()`.

Below is the code I used:

```
function getImage() {
    navigator.device.capture.captureImage(onSuccess,
        onFail,
        { 
             limit: 1
        });
}

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    alert("Image taken");
}

function onFail(error) {
    alert("Fail when getting image. Code = " = error.code);
}
```

With this code, I'm able to trigger camera to get a photo, and the photo take is saved to photo library of iPad (I only tested this on iPad2 iOS 4.3.5, haven't tested it on iPhone yet).